# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have written a rake task to update my database which I am doing by a model. I have called the function of model inside my rake task like this:

```
 get_first_student = Student.get_first_id
```

I have written the model Student like following:

```
class Students < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :id, :roll_num :name, :class
self.table_name = 'students'

if Rails.env == "development"
  CONN1 = establish_connection :adapter => "mysql2",
        :database => "mydb_dev",
        :username => "root",
        :password => "" ,
        :host => "localhost"

  CONN2 = establish_connection :adapter => "mysql2",
        :database => "mydb2_dev",
        :username => "root",
        :password => "",
        :host => "1.2.3.4"
 else
  CONN1 = establish_connection :adapter => "mysql2",
        :database => "mydb_prod",
        :username => "root",
        :password => "" ,
        :host => "localhost" 

  CONN2 = establish_connection :adapter => "mysql2",
        :database => "mydb2_prod",
        :username => "root",
        :password => "" ,
        :host => "localhost"
 end

 def self.get_first_id
   p "****"
   p CONN1
   p "****"
   sql = %Q{SELECT MIN(id) FROM mydb.students;}
   first_student_id = CONN1.connection.execute(sql).first[0]
   return first_student_id
 end
```

After running, I am getting this following output:

```
 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x007f948c223120 @mon_owner=nil,     
 @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x007f948c2230d0>, @spec=#    
 <ActiveRecord::Base::ConnectionSpecification:0x007f948c2232d8 @config=
{:adapter=>"mysql2",:database=>"mydb_dev", :username=>"root", :password=>"", 
:host=>"localhost"}, @adapter_method="mysql2_connection">, @reserved_connections={}, 
@queue=#<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x007f948c223080 @monitor=#
<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x007f948c223120 ...>, @cond=#
<ConditionVariable:0x007f948c223058 @waiters=[], @waiters_mutex=#
<Mutex:0x007f948c223008>>>, @timeout=5, @size=5, @connections=[], 
@automatic_reconnect=false>

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

Comment: Looks like it's unable to connect - do you have MYSQL setup on your localhost?

Comment: Yes I have set MYSQL setup in my localhost.

Comment: Is it running when you call the query?

Comment: No it is not running.

Comment: Should try it running!

Answer (score 0):

In rails, there are two different adapter for mysql server one in mysql and mysql2 gem. Check if you have mysql gem in your gemfile. If not, then open rails console, and type ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("mysql://your_username:yourpassword@localhost/yourdatabasename"). Have you configured your mysql server. Are you getting error in all environments?.  Check it by login into mysql server using command 'mysql -u USERNAME -p' by default its root and with not password.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `establish_connection` the second time has [disconnected](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c42b355c39547a44b4ae8677c88ee9959ebf572d/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L1043) the first pool you created and that's the `CONN1` you're trying to use.

Although this method returns a `ConnectionPool` object that you can capture and use, it's worth avoiding. ActiveRecord manages the connection pools and unless you explicitly tell it differently will assume you only want one of them active. Recently they've added some [nice new ways to manage multiple databases](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html).